# OpenNMS in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, opennms

I just learned that Apache ActiveMQ is shipping OpenNMS with it. Can anyone give me a short explanation about what OpenNMS is doing for Active MQ? My guess is it's using OpenNMS to detect all available brokers to form some kind of cluster (for failover etc.).

Now to the interesting part: is there a way to disable OpenNMS and if there is, what will be the consequences?

I'm thinking about it because OpenNMS I was pointed to some unfixed security issues within OpenNMS.

Thanks for your advice and regards. Sebastian

Comment: I see no evidence of OpenNMS being used by ActiveMQ

Comment: While OpenNMS can be used to monitor ActiveMQ using JMX it is not shipped or otherwise related to ActiveMQ. You may be confusing it with NMS - the .NET API for ActiveMQ